# Как правильно организовать реконнект и проверку соединения к серверу вебсокет?

Tags: golang, websocket

Суть проблемы, есть сокет сервер на питон реализован на ченелсах gjango, есть сервис на go, конекчусь к серверу, устанавливается соединение, далее я кладу вебсокет сервер, на клиенте ни какой информации о том что сокет соединение упало. Попробовал использовать реконнект  библу https://github.com/recws-org/recws,
Тоже самое, не видит, что коннект упал, проверяю isConnectid возвращает тру (хотя сервер лег) пытаюсь отправить сообщение, пишет ошибку и только после этого соединяется, но через какое-то время на серваке вижу сообщение что соект соединение опять упало. Потратил уже несколько дней куда копать не знаю, как правильно сделать тоже не знаю.

Comment: Вам нужно на клиентской стороне время от времени посылать сообщения Ping и считать пропущенные ответы Pong.

Comment: Добрый вечер, я посылаю в кипэлайве каждые 10 секунд пинг месседж, но именно на этом сразу и валится коннект, причем не понятно что валит джанго ченелз или го. В библе го кипэлайв ждет понг 10секунд, но соединение закрывается сразу, а в джнго ченелз  в методе ресив вообще ни чего не приходит.

Comment: Джанго должен нормально поддерживать пинги. Скорее всего, валится по иной причине, а пинги лишь диагностика

Comment: Понял почему валится соединение, го ждет ответа от ченелс ввиде тайп. Вебсокет.пингмесседж а ченелз походу умеет только либо текст, либо байты типы